# converting a matrix with headers into a .txt file

Tags: matlab, import, header, text-files

If I have a matrix of dimensions [m n] and I need to import the matrix into a tab delimited .txt file i would use:

dlmwrite(Filename, Data, 'delimiter', '\t');

However, what do I need to do if i require a header above each column in the .txt file? Where I need to define each seperate column which refer to different data sets.

thanks

Comment: What language is this? (you should tag it accordingly)

Comment: sorry, language is matlab (2011b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silvado has the right idea. Here's a hack I use from time to time:

```
outfile = '/path/to/file/output.out';
data = magic(5);
header='feat1,feat2,feat3,feat4,feat5'; 
dlmwrite(outfile,header,'delimiter','');
dlmwrite(outfile,data,'delimiter',',','-append');
```

The result is a csv file with the headers as the first line. Note the hack is to pass an empty  delimiter of `''` to dlmwrite along with a precompiled header (you could create this in a loop to automate). If performance is a big concern you may be better off using low-level functions.

Comment: although this works in importingthe data into a .txt file, the format of the output is not what I needed. The output comes all in one row instead of in the same dimensions as the 'data' matrix.

Comment: You may want to check your matrices. dlmwrite maintains the matrix formatting, see http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to write the column headers first using low-level file IO, e.g. `fprintf`. Then you can write your matrix in the very same file using the `'-append'` option to `dlmwrite`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the nicely aligned columns produced by `save` and use `dlmwrite` just to get the headers right.

```
outfile = '/path/to/file/output.out';
data = magic(5);
header='feat1  feat2  feat3  feat4  feat5'; 
dlmwrite(outfile, header, 'delimiter', '');
save(outfile, data, '-ascii', '-append');
```